# Javascript sorting numbers and text

Tags: javascript, arrays, columnsorting

how would I sort this using .sort() function in javascript? I know I can add a comparison function here but I'm not sure how I would program this.

Before

```
1 024c
100 000c
143c
1 020c
10 000c
```

After

```
143c
1 020c
1 024c
10 000c
100 000c
```

Comment: What is format in which you are getting this input? On what basis are you sorting this? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you show your first implementation.

Comment: @void I am trying to order a table column which text similar to this. I have tried the very basic return a-b which works for columns which only has text

Comment: @confusedOne see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is an array then you can use a comparator function

`(a,b) => a.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "") - b.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")`

this will remove `c` and `space` from the string to form number and compare. See the code below.

```js
var data = ["1 024c",
"100 000c",
"143c",
"1 020c",
"10 000c"]

var sorted = data.sort( (a,b) => a.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "") - b.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: This looks good, but you might want to replace `/ |c/g` with either `/\D/g` or `/[^\d.]/g`.  The first one keeps only digits.  The second keeps only digits and decimals.

Comment: @ScottSauyet makes sense. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to sort it based on the numbers in them, while excluding spaces.

```
x.sort(
    (eachObj, prevObj) => 
    parseInt(eachObj.replace(" ","")) - parseInt(prevObj.replace(" ","")) 
);
```

In ES6

Comment: Note that this gives back `["143c", "1020c", "1024c", "10000c", "100000c"]`, which is not what's wanted.  You need to retain the spaces after sort.

Comment: @ScottSauyet missed that. Edited. Thx.